# Identify unique mappings among two columns

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets where there are multiple many-to-one mappings like so:

```
Col1    Col2
abc     123
abc     123
def     456
pqr     123
xyz     789
```

How do I separate out only the unique mappings here?

That is, I want the following result:

```
Col1    Col2
abc     123
def     456
pqr     123
xyz     789
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
=unique(A1:B4)
```

where col A holds the names and B the numbers ?

In case of non-consecutive columns (e.g. col A and C), try:

```
=unique({A:A,C:C})
```

or,depending on your locale:

```
=unique({A:A\C:C})
```

Comment: what if the columns are non-consecutive?

Comment: `=unique({A:A,C:C})` worked for Google sheets having non-consecutive columns